# Убрать синоним парсинг, parsing → синтаксический-анализ

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток, замена-меток

Предлагаю убрать синоним [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) [parsing](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) → [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) и заменить тег обратно на [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) для всех вопросов, не связанных напрямую с синтаксическим анализом.

Под парсингом подразумевается:

- [разбор строки](https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/parsing), извлечение из нее 
  данных.
- десериализация.
- лексический или лексический + синтаксический анализ.

В первом значении parsing употребляется гораздо чаще. Почти все вопросы, на которые авторы ставят [парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3), подразумевают именно извлечение данных из строк.

[синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) - это вполне конкретный процесс преобразования потока лексем в абстрактное синтаксическое дерево.

Картинка [из википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages) для прояснения разницы между парсингом и синтаксическим анализом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текущее решение, насколько я понял - это руками снимать [синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7) со всех вопросов по парсингу, на которых сработал синоним. Если учесть часто возникающие вопросы "как распарсить файл/html/друзей VK" - это не слишком удачный подход, IMHO.

Comment: Вы меня убедили еще в прошлом вопросе про парсер. Поддерживаю предложение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо. я вынес в отдельный вопрос, т.к. Nicolas начал вручную удалять метек синтаксический-анализ с последних вопросов.

Comment: Возможно стоит использовать какой-либо русскоязычный термин вместо "парсинг"?

Comment: Не думаю. Парсинг -- это хороший короткий профессиональный термин.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky согласен с avp. кстати [парсер - тоже вполне русское слово, если верить википедии](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80)

Comment: В моем понимании, "парсинг" - это разбор/обработка/анализ. "парсер" - это существительное, как и "парсинг". С той разницей, что второе означает процесс. Как минимум, "парсинг" - не является словом русского языка, так как это просто транслит. На мой взгляд, оно очень-очень режет ухо, как и "парсить", "пропарсить". Кроме того, у меня большие сомнения относительного того, что "парсер" - это слово русского языка.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky в русском языке нет другого короткого слова для "лексический и синтаксический анализатор". даже википедия, при всем буквоедстве местных, использует слово "парсер" во всех статьях про лексический/ситаксический анализ. не думаю, что стоит давить жаргонизмы и пропихивать "классические" термины - которые точно так же являются жаргонизмами, только чуть более древними (в 18 веке можно было  воровать слова с французского, а нам уже нельзя?)

Comment: Анализ - отличный вариант перевода для "парсинг", на мой взгляд.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky анализ -  слишком общий термин. лучше уж "разбор". но я бы оставил "парсинг" - его чаще всего вписывают сами топикастеры.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а раз чаще вписывают - то чаще и гуглят по нему, так что стоит его оставить, imo.

Comment: Если нужен более русский термин, я бы тоже предложил «разбор». Или там «разбор-текста». Парсинг на мой вкус подразумевает наличие _парсера_, то есть разбор HTML регулярками не дорос до парсинга. Но это лишь моё ощущение языка, оно может подводить.