# Проблема синонимизации меток

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, синонимы-меток

Получил недавно новую привилегию "создавать синонимы". Решил попробовать... Все уже, конечно, создано...

Но вот я о чем подумал:

По правилам, чтобы работать с синонимами меток, надо набрать минимум 5 баллов на них. В принципе это логично и понятно. Но как быть с метками, по которым (как мне кажется) невозможно набрать каких-либо баллов.

Например, в метке [книги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8) предложен синоним [литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0). Однако из-за 5ти бального ограничения за это даже проголосовать нельзя. Ну по крайней мере я не могу.
Я не могу себе представить возможность набрать по `книги` или `литература` аж 5 баллов.
И, если я прав, получится, что такого уровня метки и связи у нас будут висеть вечно...

Итак вопросы:

1. Есть ли привилегия, где человек имеет возможность работать с метками в обход 5-ти бального ограничения?
   Т.е., чтобы знать, что теоретически хоть кто-то может это все
   вычистить, когда руки дойдут...
2. Не кажется ли участникам, что 5 баллов - многовато для таких меток?
3. Может я все-таки не прав, и на все метки можно набрать баллы?

Comment: Большую часть вопросов в тегах "книги" и "литература" можно просто закрыть.

Comment: Привилегия есть у модераторов.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть ли привилегия, где человек имеет возможность работать с метками в обход 5-ти бального ограничения?

Да, модератор может. Но практика показывает, что синонимизация через модератора чревата ошибками.

- [требуется синоним: parsing → синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/559/181472)
- [Убрать синоним парсинг, parsing → синтаксический-анализ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1101/181472)

> Не кажется ли участникам, что 5 баллов - многовато для таких меток?

Мне так не кажется. Если участник не смог набрать и пяти баллов по метке, то ему не стоит пока заниматься синонимами. Данные две метки представляют собой некоторое исключение: возможность задавать по ним вопросы существенно ограничена (сейчас, но не раньше). Не думаю, что ради них нужно что-то менять.

> Может я все-таки не прав, и на все метки можно набрать баллы?

За не-общие ответы можно. По литературе есть [20 голосующих участников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0/topusers), [по книгам столько же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/topusers). Их вполне хватит, чтобы синонимизировать эти метки нормальным путём.

Если хотите, можете стимулировать этот процесс ([пример](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1320/181472)).

Comment: *синонимизация через модератора чревата ошибками* — любопытное утверждение, учитывая оценку +3/–3 у второго поста.

Comment: @Discord в первом на ответе один голос (мой, не могу снять). Для синонимизации потребовалось бы +4. То есть нормальным путем синоним даже не был бы создан.

Comment: Там +2/–1 и у вопроса, и у ответа.

Comment: @Discord с телефона не вижу голоса. Ну и +2 это не +4.